# Multiply vector categories

Tags: grass-gis

I have imported a Vector map into GRASS GIS. There are some problems with the topology and some polygon areas overlap.

I used 'v.clean' to break overlapping polygons and now I have multiple polygons mapped to the same category in the attribute table.

Is there any way to convert this feature to category mapping so that each feature maps to a separate category? I don`t care that I will have duplicate information in the attribute table.

All I want, is that starting from the original vector map (that has 1000 features and 1000 corresponding records in the attribute table), that after running 'v.clean' and obtaining 1500 features to have 1500 corresponding records in the attribute table.

Can this be done?